# Get cloud Firestore data into a User Model class to use these data into the app in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have built all my Frontend App with Flutter, and the user information came from a model class I have created.

```
class Client {
  final int id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String nickName;
  final String emailAddress;
  final String imageProfile;

  const Client({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.nickName,
    this.emailAddress,
    this.imageProfile,
  });
}

final Client currentUser = Client(
  id: 0,
  firstName: data['document_from_firestore'],
  lastName: data['document_from_firestore'],
  nickName: data['document_from_firestore'],
  emailAddress: data['document_from_firestore'],
  imageProfile: data['document_from_firestore'],
);
```

now I want to pass the data to the widget using:  `currentUser.firstName` etc...
this file should be always updated with Stream or Future and into the Screens I have the data updated.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question maybe more clear.